# Sampling from exponential Bernoulli

Tags: python, sampling, normal-distribution, bernoulli-probability, bernoulli-numbers

Bernoulli is a probability distribution. I need to sample from an exponential bernoulli and returns a binary value (i.e. either 0 or 1). I found this algorithm [exponential bernoulli sampling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRMVw.png)
and i want to implement it but i do not understand the step 3 of the algorithm where :
 `r1 = r1 & (2^h - 1 )`.
Could someone give help ?

Comment: If it is a question about the algorithm remove the Python tag. Ortherwise please include full code to be checked, sample input and output/error message. Is it working or not ? If not Maybe & should be replaced by "and"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a library which implements sampling from a Bernoulli distribution, e.g., `np.random.binomial` (as [the binomial distribution with n = 1 is the Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)).

```
import numpy as np
np.random.binomial(n=1, p=.2, size=20)
# output: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Downvoted - it might be a way to sample, but it has nothing do to with the question which is regarding `r1 = r1 & (2^h-1)`

Comment: The question says "I need to sample from an exponential bernoulli and ...", so "don't reinvent the wheel" is an answer.

Comment: No, it's not an answer to the question. The question is specific stated as the `r1` part, and not "how to sample in Python".